# ActionBarSherlock change home icon layout

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

Is there any easy way to change the home icon layout (margins, padding, background) in ActionBarSherlock that isn't a total hack? Right now, in onCreate, I am essentially finding the home icon by id, and setting the params. This works ok, but in a situation where I have an expandable view, and expanding it triggers the creation of a new, separate homeview, I would have to figure out how to manipulate that as well.

I am getting into the territory where I have to start subclassing the abs classes just to accomplish this. Is there an easier way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try modifying `abs__home` ImageView parameters in the `abs__action_bar_home.xml` from `res/layout` in the ABS sources.

Having said that, it's, probably, not a very good idea to modify home icon layout..

Comment: That would only affect compatibility mode though, wouldn't it? If it's ICS or greater I would think that it uses a different layout. I'll give it a shot.